# Разное отображение css стилей на разных устройствах

Tags: html, css

прошу помочь разобраться что не так с кнопкой. На компьютере она выглядит так [image: скриншот с компьютера]

А на телефоне так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала думала что это из за разных размеров экрана, добавляла @media, но это не помогло, так как сайт открывается в телеграме и открывается полная версия сайта, то есть размеры экрана не влияют на код

Пыталась выставлять значения не в px, а в %, но все равно кнопка была больше, чем надо

Есть ли предположения что с этой кнопкой не так?

Весь мой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style>

 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');

    body {

    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #333333;
    }
    h1{
        color: #fcfbf9;
        margin-left: 650px;
         margin-top: 40px;
        width: 200px;

    }
    button {

        font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
        border: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 630px;
         margin-top: 30px;
        height: 90px;
        width: 250px;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 500ms ease;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #808080;
    }
    input {
        font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
        border: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 630px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 245px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 250;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 500ms ease;
        color: #000000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Введите код</h1>
</div>
<!--    <form id="form">-->
<h2></h2>
<input type='text' placeholder="Код" id="user_code">
<br />
<button id="send">Отправить</button>
<!--    </form>-->
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
<script>
    let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    let send = document.getElementById("send");
    tg.expand();

    send.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        let code = document.getElementById("user_code").value;
        let data ={
        code: code
        }
        tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
        tg.close();
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как минимум, у Вас указана разная ширина для инпута (width: 245px) и для кнопки (width: 250px;) и зачем Вам бордеры по 10 и 30 пикселей?

Answer (score 2):

Разные браузеры на разных платформах имеют различные начальные стили для элементов. Поэтому необходимо либо сбрасывать стили, либо явно их указать.

Думаю, что ваша проблема кроется в отсутствии свойства `box-sizing`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #000; background-color: #333;
}

h1 { color: #fcfbf9; }

input {
  height: 40px; width: 250px;
  border: none; border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 250 20px/1em 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

button {
  height: 90px; width: 250px;
  border: none; border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 25px/1em 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #000; background-color: #808080;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>Введите код</h1>
</div>
<!--    <form id="form">-->
<input type='text' placeholder="Код" id="user_code">
<button id="send">Отправить</button>
<!--    </form>-->
```

Для выравнивания элементов лучше применять *flex* или *grid*, а `padding` и `margin` использовать по прямому назначению, т.е. для отступов.